# Use Expo Metro Bundler instead of react-native start

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

currently I'm migrating my react native app to expo bare workflow. Everything it's been fine so far, except for the following.

This may seem like a noob mistake, but I'm unable to use the Metro Bundler from Expo when I run my app from Xcode. Before, I could run from Xcode and the simulator would appear in the Metro Bundler with all it's logs, that was very useful.

I've been searching this for a couple days and the closest thing I've found to what I want, is using `expo build:ios`. The problem, it pops up a warning saying that if I'm not sure what I'm doing it's best to leave it as it is. It's a big application so I'm worried it might lead to errors, therefore I didn't do it.

If anyone knows for sure if this command is what I'm looking for, or has a better suggestion, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

[EDIT]

To be more specific, I don't mean using the `Expo Go` app. I mean a standalone app (I'm not sure if this is the correct term for it). Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

`expo build:ios` is used for building an app bundle for your application. This is used when you want to publish your application on the store and that is why it asks for credentials of developer account on the iOS.

If you just want to run your app and check then you should use `expo start`. This will start the Metro Bundler for you and then you can run your application on your device scanning the QR code that would appear there.

Comment: Thanks for the information on the ```expo build:ios```. Although, this isn't the answer I was looking for, at the bottom you can see that I don't mean using the Expo Go App.